# How do I use a multi-value parameter with a CASE expression in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameter-passing, case, multivalue

I am trying to use a case expression to flag which records have any of the ID's listed in my parameter.  My code is something like this:

```
SELECT 
TRANSACTION_ID,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID IN (@PARAMETER) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CUSTOMER_CLASS
```

It works fine if I only use one value when it asks for a parameter, but if I put more than one I get : An Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

I've tried doing this several ways, including treating the parameter like it was a comma seperated string and trying to parse the substring.  I can't figure out how the parameter is passed, but I keep getting problems.

I'm at wits end.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is @ PARAMETER declared in your query or is it from SSRS? Are you using @ parameter anywhere else? SSRS should handle the parsing for multiple values so it *should* work.

Comment: As Hannover states, this SHOULD work. Is the SQL snippet directly from your dataset query or are you calling a stored proc? If it's a stored proc your code won't work but if the query is directly in your dataset query then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you should go for Dynamic query.
Below code is working perfect.

```
        Declare  @sql varchar(max), 
                 @PARAMETER varchar(100) = '1,2,3,4' //For ex
        set @sql = 
            'SELECT 
            TRANSACTION_ID,
            CASE WHEN CUSTOMER_ID IN ('+@PARAMETER+') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CUSTOMER_CLASS'; 
Execute(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case when [ReturnedBy] IN (SELECT Split FROM [dbo].[ufn_Split](@param_1, ',')) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: can you please add some context as to what this snippet does?

Comment: Select Col_1 = case when [ReturnedBy] IN (SELECT Split FROM [dbo].[ufn_Split](@param_1, ',')) then 1 else 0 end
from table_1
Since suggested above that he/she already has a split function. We use this on our ssrs / sql procs all the time. Any errors can be limited to function not the call of function.

Comment: If you're adding more context to the answer, please don't use comment, only edit the answer, so it's more useful to future visitors to this question.